# iOS Swift: Match UIImage frame size with Image pixel size

Tags: ios, uiimageview, frame

I have a table view custom cell in which I am uploading images from Parse database. I want to display the Full image (as uploaded without crop). For ex: I have all the images of size 640 x 480 in the parse data base. So what should be the size of UIImageView frame in my UITableView cell?

I need aspect fit functionality. Aspect fit gives me the full image but I have to struggle to see which frame size to select. Is there a formula to get the frame size depending on the image size (for ex: 640 x 480). Frame to Pixel? I can get the desired functionality with trial setting different frame view size and running the app, but I want to know if there is a standard formula to get this size depending on the image size.

For the sake of simplicity, lets keep the image size 640 x 480. So what should be the UIImageView frame size in attribute inspector to get that image in full size without using Aspect fit.